# Image is greenish in opencv capture

Tags: linux, opencv, camera, v4l2, nanopi

I am using NanoPi-M4 board with friendly elec [camera](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=78&product_id=247) and in the guide manufacture tells to use rkisp not V4L2 in gstreamer pipeline in order to get the image. However, I encountered some problems install rkisp in docker container and want to use V4L2. The problem is that image is apperaing greenish to me. First image is from V4L and second is from rkisp.

This is the line, how I get the image with v4l2. I tried to play with v4l2-ctl and change exposure and gain, but it resulted in more bright image still with greenish mask all over it.

```
v4l2src device='+self.preview_devs[index]+' io-mode=4 isp-mode=1A ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width='+str(self.cam_width)+',height='+str(self.cam_height)+',framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink
```

This is list of possible controls in camera

```
User Controls

                       exposure 0x00980911 (int)    : min=4 max=1550 step=1 default=1536 value=1536

Image Source Controls

              vertical_blanking 0x009e0901 (int)    : min=34 max=31247 step=1 default=34 value=34
            horizontal_blanking 0x009e0902 (int)    : min=4294967192 max=4294967192 step=1 default=4294967192 value=-104 flags=read-only
                  analogue_gain 0x009e0903 (int)    : min=16 max=248 step=1 default=16 value=248

Image Processing Controls

                 link_frequency 0x009f0901 (intmenu): min=0 max=0 default=0 value=0 flags=read-only
                     pixel_rate 0x009f0902 (int64)  : min=0 max=200000000 step=1 default=200000000 value=200000000 flags=read-only
                   test_pattern 0x009f0903 (menu)   : min=0 max=4 default=0 value=0
```

[image: V4l capture]

[image: rkisp capture]

Comment: Seems like a white balance issue. I think you can control it through GStreamer

Comment: @Ziri, I thought that too, but there is no possible white balance control in v4l2. I have updated question with list of possible controls.